# ArcMap: How to create legend for specific data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend

I'm coming up a problem in map production where I have two data frames, but it seems like I can only create a legend using the items in the original data frame (the order doesn't seem to matter as I can reorder them and I'm still only able to add items to the legend that are in the original data frame). I can sort of get around this by dragging all the files into the original data frame, but that results in some weird display problems.

I've gone through the Legend properties, but there doesn't seem to be anything there. Anyone have any suggestions as to how to specify which data frame is used for legend building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work how you want if you create one legend from the currently active data frame. And then you activate the other data frame and repeat by creating a new separate legend and remove the title from the second legend and then highlight both legends right click and select group? You can fix alignment problems by selecting the legends before they are grouped, right clicking then going down to the align menu. Grouping both legends essentially turns them into one. They will still update on the fly when you turn layers off or on or rename them even if the layer is not in the currently active data frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh maybe i'm making this more complicated than it is. You can right click the data frame that you want to use as a legend and click activate. It's the second to last option. The legend only pulls items from the currently active data frame.

Comment: Perfect! This was what I needed to know, that you could activate particular data frames. Simple solution. Thanks!